# Postgres - merge two tables with sum

Tags: sql, merge, postgresql-9.3

I have two tables with identical columns, a different number of lines. I need to merge these tables into one using client_id AND segment_name as the unique identifiers of a distinct entry, summing the user_count if there is a match between the two tables. Any help much appreciated.

**table A**

```
client_id | segment_name    | user_count
-------------------------------------
45845     | segment45877-58 | 2358
55255     | weather558      | 20
88890     | jobs-listing    | 558
```

**table B**

```
client_id | segment_name | user_count
--------------------------------------
45845     | segment45877-58   | 100 
55255     | weather558        | 350
2454      | leonardo-da-vinci | 5465
```

**table C (new)**

```
client_id | segment_name      | user_count
-------------------------------------
45845     | segment45877-58   | 2458
55255     | weather558        | 370
88890     | jobs-listing      | 558
2454      | leonardo-da-vinci | 5465
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try

```
CREATE TABLE C AS  
       (SELECT client_id, 
               segment_name, 
               SUM(user_count) AS user_count
        FROM   (SELECT * FROM A UNION ALL 
                SELECT * FROM B) Data 
        GROUP  BY client_id, segment_name);
```